# How can I access an array in asm?

Tags: c, gnu-assembler

```
char greet[] = "hello mate";

__asm__("\n\
movl foo, %eax\n\
");
```

How do I move `greet[0]` into a register such as `%eax`?

My guess:

```
char greet[] = "hello mate";

__asm__("\n\
movl $_greet, %ebx\n\
movl (%ebx), %eax\n\
");
```

But, I'm getting a memory error.

Comment: `greet[1]` or `greet[0]`? Why is it an `int[]`, not a `char[]`?

Comment: ahhh! mistakes. my bad, let me fix it. My heads all cloudy from the thinking.

Answer (score 1):

If `greet` is a local variable `__asm__` would not be able to reference it automatically. You may need to use an assembler template:

```
int main () {
    char greet[] = "hello mate";

    __asm__(
        "movzbl (%0), %%eax\n"
        : : "r"(greet) : "%eax"
    //      ^            ^ do not touch %eax
    //      '- set %0 to a register storing `greet`
    );

    // now %eax should store 'h' (0x68).

    return 0;
}
```